# Preserve the permissions with rsync

Tags: permissions, rsync

Let's say I have a file a.txt in LINUX with permission of 0664.
When I use rsync to copy the file to my Mac with `rsync -r -t -v LINUX MAC`, the file's permission becomes 0644.

How can I keep the permission for a file when using rsync? The -g option doesn't work.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You want the -p flag:

```
    -p, --perms                 preserve permissions
```

I tend to always use the -a flag, which is an aggregation of -p and several other useful ones:

```
    -a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
```

Both taken straight from [the rsync manpage](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I got some errors with -a/-p option - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12203/rsync-failed-to-set-permissions-on-error-with-rsync

Comment: But does it preserve the permissions if the destination machine does not have a username equaling the one who owns the files on the source? (e.g. I have `vmail` user on source but not on target, does it preserve the username when restoring to source?)

Comment: @W.M. it's been a few years since you asked the question, but I found that the `rsync` `-a` switch also includes performs the "preserve owner" and "preserve group" options, which requires super-user. Also, you may want to consider `--numeric-ids` which won't map username/groupname

Comment: Make it an answer, @ray_voelker! :)