# Rsync fails to create symlinks when syncing with an ExFAT partition

Tags: linux, filesystems, rsync, symlink, external-hdd

I tried to sync with an ExFAT partion on an external HDD using the command:

```
rsync -avvP --remove-source-files /path/to/sourceDir /path/to/destDir
```

However I got this type of error several times:

```
rsync: [generator] symlink "/destDir/subdirectory/
" -> "A" failed: Function not implemented (38)
```

At the end of the rsync recursive copy operation, the following error was printed:

```
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1330) [sender=3.2.3]
```

The sending side is an ext4 partitioned internal hard drive.

Comment: Fortunately all the symlinks in the source directory are not important or needed.

Comment: Adjacently-related: [Super User: rsync seems to overwrite already existing file on ExFat](https://superuser.com/q/763366/425838)

Answer (score 3):

If you use the rsync option:

`rsync -a`

you will get a [function not implemented error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12203/rsync-failed-to-set-permissions-on-error-with-rsync-a-or-p-option) like:

```
rsync: [generator] symlink "/destDir/subdirectory/
" -> "A" failed: Function not implemented (38)
```

due to the limitation of the ExFAT file system. ExFAT does not support symlinks so rsync can not create one on an ExFAT file system [1](https://superuser.com/a/1256536/887472) [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178797/ln-failed-to-create-symbolic-link-function-not-implemented). See answers in this [question](https://superuser.com/a/1256536/887472) for possible workarounds.

Anecdotal evidence [3](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/issues/1057#issuecomment-582065704).

ExFAT also does not understand permissions, owners or groups [4](https://www.scivision.dev/rsync-to-exfat-drive/) so when syncing to an ExFAT partition using:
`rsync`
you will get errors like this:

```
rsync: mkstemp … failed: Function not implemented (38)
```

Comment: See here too!: https://www.scivision.dev/rsync-to-exfat-drive/ They recommend using options `-vrltD` with exFAT, rather than `-a`. As I mention [in my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1388910/425838), `-a` includes options `-rlptgoD`.

Comment: But...like you said, and [like Microsoft says here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/filesystem-functionality-comparison), exFAT does not support symlinks (soft links), so remove the `-l` and just use `-vrtD`. See also here: [SuperUser: rsync seems to overwrite already existing file on ExFat](https://superuser.com/a/1181312/425838)